# Python load unknown characters loaded in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to load email messages that I copied into rtf files (as my training data)
I load the directory containing the files using sklearn module and command:

```
    sklearn.datasets.load_files
   corpus =  sklearn.datasets.load_files(<path>,shuffle = False)
```

When I attempt to print corpus.data, the first 6000 characters or so are \x00\x00\x00\x01Bud1\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x08. Then the actual message text is displayed but intertwined are characters such as: \cf0 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0\nHey,\\ in the middle of the text.
I do want to mention that some of the text has German characters as well as English.

What could be the problem here?

Best
Ok

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for this function it says

> If you leave encoding equal to None, then the content will be made of bytes instead of Unicode, and you will not be able to use most functions in sklearn.feature_extraction.text.

Without knowing the encoding of your files you might want to try

```
sklearn.databases.load_files(<path>,shuffle = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The error after adding utf-8 is UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte. I tried resaving the rtf file as utf-8 but no change as well. When I try load a txt file the data is empty.

Comment: try `encoding='latin-1`, this is the second most common encoding (windows default)

Comment: I tried that and windows-1252 but neither produce a different result. I tried adding ' load_content= True, encoding='utf-8' in all encoding combinations but nothing changed. The script is utf-8, the rtf files are originally email messages. I'm using OS X.

Comment: whats wrong with encoding='utf-8', i'm confused how it works with latin-1 but not with utf-8